# Using $\frac n6(n+1)(2n+7)$ find, interms of $n$, the sum of the series $3\ln2+4\ln2^2+5\ln2^3+...+(n+2)\ln2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Using the result $$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+2)=\frac n6(n+1)(2n+7)$$ find, interms of $n$, the sum of the series

$$3\ln2+4\ln2^2+5\ln2^3+...+(n+2)\ln2^n$$ and express in its simplest form.

Where do I start please?

Comment: What is a proof that $\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+2) = \frac{n}{6} (n+1)(2n+7)$? Does anyone have a link?

Comment: Well, $r(r+2)=(r+1)^2-1$. So it shouldn't be hard to prove. @EricAuld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

As $\ln a^b=b\ln a,$

$$3\ln2+4\ln2^2+5\ln2^3+...+(n+2)\ln2^n=\sum_{1\le r\le n}(r+2)\ln 2^r=\ln 2\sum_{1\le r\le n}r(r+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use the fact that:
$$ \ln (a^x) = x\ln(a) $$